# Printing same thing multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know what is the problem, but its keep on printing same thing multiple time. If anyone can assist me, it will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import urllib.request


req = urllib.request.Request('http://shopnicekicks.com/products/a-ma-maniere-x-diadora-n9000-mens-brown-sugar.xml')
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
end = res.geturl()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
parsed = urlparse(end)


for variant in soup.variants.find_all("id", {"type": "integer"}):
    cart = 'http://'+parsed.netloc+'/cart/' +variant.text+':1'
    for size in soup.variants.find_all('title'):
        print(cart, size.text)
```

Comment: What's it supposed to print? And how is that supposed to be derived from the input? What does it actually print?

Comment: It suppose to print like this:
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239105:1 8
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239169:1 8.5
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239233:1 9
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239297:1 9.5
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239361:1 10
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239425:1 10.5
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239489:1 11
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239553:1 12
    http://shopnicekicks.com/cart/23839239617:1 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your find is too high up so you end up getting all the titles in the document for each id in the document. Do the finds inside each variant.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import urllib.request


req = urllib.request.Request('http://shopnicekicks.com/products/a-ma-maniere-x-diadora-n9000-mens-brown-sugar.xml')
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
end = res.geturl()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
parsed = urlparse(end)

for variant in soup.variants.find_all("variant"):
    cart = 'http://'+parsed.netloc+'/cart/' +variant.id.text+':1'
    size = variant.find("title")
    print(cart, size.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Should your `print(cart, size.text)` not be `print(size, size.text)` ?